# Custom Ribbon Drop Down Element - How to View Id, Index, Label for Each Item in Drop Down

Tags: excel, vba, ribbonx

I have created a custom ribbon for an Excel workbook. I used the Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office
to create the XML. I also used the Custom UI Editor to generate callbacks. I modified the callbacks slightly
for my workbook. The custom ribbon has just one element - a dropdown.

The Excel data that I used to populate the dropdown is below, in worksheet "Companies". The rows are in sorted order, by company name.
The first and last rows are fictitious companies, and just there to help my debugging.

```
1/1/2022  AAAAA             0
1/15/2022 ABC CO   Pencils 100
1/31/2022 DEF CO   Paper    25
2/1/2022  XYZ INC  Pens   120
1/1/2022  ZZZZZ             0
```

The drop down menu displays the company name. In the callback DropDown_getSelectedItemID() I specified Cells(2,2), which is "ABC CO",
so that the drop down would be set to that ID by default.

There is clearly a problem. If I use the drop down to select "ABC CO", which is already selected in the drop down, the onAction event
does not fire. I know that because I print a message when the onAction event fires. But if I select the next row, DEF CO",
onAction does fire.

It would be very helpful if I could view the index, ID and label for each of items in the drop down. It might show me that
the ID is null, or indicate the problem. But I don't know how to view that data for each item. I would be very grateful for help on that.

Below are the callbacks I use. If anyone sees an error in them I hope you will let me know. Thanks very much.

```
VBA Code:
Option Explicit
'testRibbon is a variable which contains the Ribbon
Public testRibbon As IRibbonUI

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Public Sub testRibbon_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
   Set testRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

'Callback for DropDown getItemCount
Public Sub DropDown_getItemCount(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
   returnedVal = 5
End Sub

'Callback for DropDown getItemLabel
Public Sub DropDown_getItemLabel(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef returnedVal)
   returnedVal = Worksheets("Companies").Cells(index + 1, 2)
End Sub

'Callback for DropDown onAction
Public Sub DropDown_onAction(control As IRibbonControl, id As String, index As Integer)
   MsgBox index + " was selected"
End Sub

Public Sub DropDown_getItemID(control As IRibbonControl, index As Integer, ByRef id)
   'This Callback will set the id for each item created.
   'It provides the index value within the Callback.
   'The index is the position within the drop-down list.
   id = Worksheets("Companies").Cells(index + 1, 2)
End Sub

Public Sub DropDown_getSelectedItemID(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef id)
   'This Callback will change the drop-down to be set to a specific id.
   'This could be used to set a default value or reset the first item in the list
   id = Worksheets("Companies").Cells(2, 2)
End Sub

Public Sub updateRibbon()
'This is a standard procedure, not a Callback.  It is triggered by the button.
'It invalidates the Ribbon, which causes it to re-load.

On Error Resume Next
   testRibbon.Invalidate
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Clarify how the Ribbon Drop Down menu is created.  Is it dynamically created from the contents of worksheet "Companies"?

Comment: Yes. The drop down is filled by the code in the callbacks when you first open the drop down.  A callback runs which gets the item count.  In my code I set that to 5.  In fact I use a function which returns the # of rows with data in Col A of worksheet "Companies".  Then I believe callback getItemID() runs.  It provides an index # (the first time it runs it's 0), and the VBA code returns an ID.  I set that to Worksheets("Companies").Cells(index + 1, 2), which is the first company name, in row 1 col B.  I wish I could look at the index, ID and label of each item after the list is created.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the xml definition for the dropDown object.  Additionally the call back for onAction, the MsgBox, replace the + with &.

Comment: Hi igittr,
I'm sorry for not replying sooner.  I got bogged down with another project.  But I'm ready now to resume work on solving the problem I'm having with the dropdown.  Are you still available to help?  If so, I'll explain the problem in detail.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, here's the XML:
    <customUI onLoad="testRibbon_onLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
<tabs>
<tab id="Tab1" label="Jobs on Hiatus">
<group id="Group1" label="Jobs on Hiatus">
<dropDown 
   id="DropDown"
   label="Select Job To&#xA;Return from Hiatus"
   getItemCount="DropDown_getItemCount"
   getItemID="DropDown_getItemID"
   getItemLabel="DropDown_getItemLabel"
   getSelectedItemID="DropDown_getSelectedItemID"
   onAction="DropDown_onAction" />
</group>
</tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>

Comment: I admit that I was not aware of this feature, and was intrigued with the possibilities.  After working through the details I was able to create a drop down and experiment with it.  Like any drop down in VBA, clicking on the currently selected entry does not trigger a click event, and therefore no OnAction.  No event is triggered in this case.  I would  guess you will need to capture necessary information when the OnAction event occurs and reference it when you need to apply it to the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force an OnAction every time there is a selection, the Drop Down needs to be reset to a blank value after each selection.  Add a blank value to the list of values in the Companies work sheet, as the first entry. Increase the count by one (5 to 6).  Add this to the XML `getLabel="DropDown_GetLabel"`. Add this to your OnAction call back to save the selected item index and then reset the control to default.  Create the sSelectedItem as a global variable.

```
sSelectedItem = index + 1
updateRibbon
```

Add this to your Call Backs to value the Drop Down label with the currently selected item.

```
Public Sub DropDown_getLabel(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef label)
        on error resume next  ' to handle initial open of workbook
        label = Worksheets("Companies").Cells(sSelectedItem, 2)
End Sub
```

and finally update the set default callback to select the zero (blank) entry.

```
Public Sub DropDown_getSelectedItemIndex(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef idx)
   idx = 0  '<<<<
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi igittr,

Thank you so much for the explanation and the code snippets.  I haven't tried your changes yet because I want to ask a question first.  You have Sub DropDown_getLabel.  But I already have Sub DropDown_getItemLabel.  Would it be better to use the names for subs that you use?  If you are willing to look at my code, I have placed it at this URL:

https://www.mathtutor.com/DropDown.txt

BTW, I have another question, which I would prefer to e-mail to you.  
Please let me know if this is OK.  My e-mail is: cblaine84@gmail.com
Thanks!